# function inside list comprehension - is it evaluated multiple times

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Which one's a better way of doing list comprehension in python (in terms of computation time & cpu cycles). 
In example (1) is the value f(r) evaluated in each iteration or is it evaluated once and cached ?

1. `y = [x*f(r) for x in xlist]`
2. `c = f(r)`

   `y = [x*c for x in xlist]`

where

```
def f(r):
    ... some arbitrary function ...
```

Comment: "Is the choice dependent on how complicated f(r) evaluation is ?"  How do you define "complicated" here?  And, more importantly, when and how does Python do this determination of "complexity".  And, even more importantly, when the `f(r)` involves `eval()`, how can **anything** be determined?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant should 'I', as the user choose between (1) & (2) depending on function complexity or should I always choose (2).

Comment: @ensnap: What?  "Is the value f(r) evaluated once and cached ?"  In the 2nd example, yes.  In the first example, no.  And Python (given the existence of `eval()`, cannot optimize this for you.  What are you asking?  Please **update** the question to be more clear.

Comment: @ensnap: "should 'I', as the user choose" and "is the function evaluated multiple times" are completely different.  Please fix the title or the question to match each other better.  It's very confusing.

Comment: @S.Lott The title asks "is the function evaluated multiple times in a list comprehension". The answer from the response is yes. So (2) is a better approach.

Comment: @ensnap: Please **update** the question so that the title, the question and all of your various comments agree with each other.  It's still not clear what -- exactly -- you want to know.  The answer to the title doesn't answer the question you have in your comments.  It's very hard to figure out what you're talking about.  Please simplify and focus the question.

Comment: @S.Lott made the question & title more elaborate. Feel free to add your edit - thanks.

Comment: @ensnap: I can't edit.  I simply don't understand the question.  "Which one's a better way" and "is it evaluated once and cached?" are two unrelated things.  And the title is a simple statement of fact that seems to make the "is it evaluated once and cached?" needless.  I'm sorry to be difficult, but I can't understand what you want to know.  What problem do you have?  What information do you need?

Comment: They are related. Since the function is evaluated only once in case (2), it's a better way in terms of time / cycles for computation. Case (1) requires more cycles.

Comment: @ensnap: I simply don't understand the question. "Which one's a better way" and "is it evaluated once and cached?" are two **separate** questions.  Yes, there's a tiny thread of connecting logic, but only if you **assume** an answer to the second question.  I find this confusing.  If you're asking, please don't assume.  If you're assuming please don't ask.  The mixture of assumption and asking makes the question somewhat hard to follow.

Comment: @S.Lott If you read carefully, the complete question is "Which one's a better way in terms of computation time & cpu cycles". IMO the 2 questions are pretty straight forward & have a strong connection.

Comment: @ensnap: I'm asking you to please clear it up so that "read carefully" is not required.

Comment: The other duplicate contains a better answer. If you do feel that this dupe is unfair please do @ping me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would probably choose the latter because the Python compiler doesn't know if the function has side-effects so it is called for each element.

Comment: "probably"?  Considering that the function could use `eval()`, what other choice can there possibly be?

Comment: I said probably because I hadn't written any code to confirm my theory.

Comment: How can Python possibly "know if the function has side-effects"?  The function could use `eval()` or `exec` and do **anything**.  Since `eval()` exists, the function must be evaluated every single time or the semantics are horribly broken.

Comment: @S Lott Why does the presence of eval guarantee that Python interpreter can't ever be sure that there's no side effects?

Answer (score 14):

It evaluates for every iteration. Look at this:

```
>>> def f():
...     print("func")
... 
>>> [f() for i in range(4)]
func
func
func
func
[None, None, None, None]
```

As you say, if f() has no side effects, storing the return value on a variable and using that variable instead is a lot faster solution.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an easy way to find out:

```
>>> def f():
...     print "called"
...     return 1
...
>>> [1+f() for x in xrange(5)]
called
called
called
called
called
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

so yes, if the function is going to be the same each time then it is better to call it once outside the list comprehension.

Comment: Isn't there an apply function or map function. 
Map is creating a generator object.

Comment: I just wanted to add a workaround way to avoid multiple function calls in python list comprehension: put the function call in a nested comprehension that only evaluates once. With your example, I mean this: 
`[1+ f_ for f_ in [f()] for x in xrange(5)]` -- note that 

`f()` is only called once here.

Answer (score 2):

The function `f` will be called for every element.

Answer (score 1):

It is very complex for the compiler/interpreter to determine that the function need not to be called many times. It is then very probable that the function is called many times. Thus, using the second solution is always the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Functions have a non-trivial execution time compared to a name lookup, and caching the value is considered acceptable if the function is called many times and the same value is expected each time.

Answer (score 0):

Python is probably free to do it once or many times, I'm not sure I would rely on any observed behavior. It might change in the next version.

If it's important to you to make sure the function is only called once, call it yourself and save the results.

Comment: How would it be free to do it only once?  Unless the interpreter can guarantee that `f` is side-effect free, it must call it every iteration no?

Comment: @Davy8, certainly there are ways to guarantee that a function does not have side effects. If Python does not implement any today, it is still free to do so in the future.

Comment: If the function uses `eval()` nothing can be determined.  Therefore there's no alternative by evaluation of the function each time through the loop.  Yes, a future version **could** break the semantics, but the idea of `eval()` is too fundamental to break.

Comment: @S.Lott: then part of the determination would be "does this function call `eval`? You couldn't accurately classify every function, but it would certainly be possible to identify some simple functions that had no side effects - at least when called with built-in types.

Comment: @Thomas K: What?  How much time do you want to wait while Python does all this reasoning about the code?  There's no probably and there's nothing this complex going on.  The rules are simple and unlikely to change.  Your final statement "if it's important..." is **very** relevant.  The rest can be dropped because it's all supposition.

Comment: @S.Lott: I didn't think it was doing anything this complex. But in principle, it's perfectly possible that it could, so the question isn't as stupid as you make out.

Comment: @Thomas K: "But in principle, it's perfectly possible that it could"  There are two limits on this.  First, there's a pragmatic limit on the magical things that "could" be done. It seems clear that the presence of `eval()` makes this impractical.  Also, the essential impossibility of determining whether or not the function being applied even terminates, makes any analysis of that function impossible.  Since there are two reasons that no inspection of the function can be done, I'd think that was sufficient reason to expect no analysis.  However, I grant you, it *could* be done.

Comment: @S.Lott, when analyzing a function for side effects there are three possible outcomes: yes, no, and can't tell. You seem to think the existence of the third precludes the other two, but it does not. As long as the yes/can't tell cases are lumped together the optimization will be safe. Analyzing the code might even come for free with certain JIT techniques.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: The can't tell is -- sadly -- undecidable.  You can't make the decision in finite time.