# Python: Is the split function evaluated multiple times in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

There is something I've been wondering about for a while. Is the split executed once or multiple times in this list comprehension?

```
l = [line.split()[i] for i in indexes]
```

I currently do list comprehensions like these in this way:

```
l = line.rstrip().split()
l = [l for i in indexes]
```

But I'm not sure, whether it's necessary. In addition to a yes/no answer I would definitely like to know, how I could go about finding out about this myself by either by doing CPU profiling or reading some documentation. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python : function inside list comprehension - is it evaluated multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155008/python-function-inside-list-comprehension-is-it-evaluated-multiple-times)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression on the left in a list comprehension is evaluated anew for each element, yes.

If you only need it evaluated once, you need to do exactly what you did; call it first and store the result to be re-used in the list comprehension.

From the [*List displays* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

> In this case, the elements of the new list are those that would be produced by considering each of the `for` or `if` clauses a block, nesting from left to right, **and evaluating the expression to produce a list element each time the innermost block is reached**.

Emphasis mine.

You could also disassemble the list comprehension using the [`dis.dis()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('[line.split()[i] for i in indexes]', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (indexes)
              6 GET_ITER            
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                22 (to 32)
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (i)
             13 LOAD_NAME                2 (line)
             16 LOAD_ATTR                3 (split)
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             22 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
             25 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             26 LIST_APPEND              2
             29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   32 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `FOR_ITER` opcode starts the loop (with the `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` closing it), and each time a `LOAD_NAME line`, `LOAD_ATTR split` and `CALL_FUNCTION` are executed. In other words, the bytecodes 13 through to 19 implement the `line.split()` part, and it is executed each time through the loop, which runs from bytecodes 7 through to 29.

(Python 3 note: list comprehensions got their own scope and you'll need to extract the code object from the outer code object constants; `dis.dis(compile('[line.split()[i] for i in indexes]', '', 'eval').co_consts[0])`).

Comment: Thanks, I found out it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155008/python-function-inside-list-comprehension-is-it-evaluated-multiple-times

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: I didn't think there was a either a documentation or the disassembly option out there yet.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: another community member just duped in this direction, presumably because they felt this answer covered the bases better.

Comment: I translated your edit as I didn't see that you added more info in time. Well, disassembly translates to what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add that your example of LC is an replacement for:

```
l = []
for i in indexes:
    l.append(line.split()[i])
```

So,the answer is most definitely Yes, it's evaluated each time per iteration.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dalen says, when reasoning about a list comprehension, I believe you can expect it to behave just as if you'd done the same thing without a comprehension. @Martijn shows how you can verify this by looking at the assembly.

My answer

1. Provides an easier method to verify the behavior yourself (in the sense that you don't need to read assembly).
2. Shows the behavior for a function in multiple places within the list comprehension (I found this question when I was wondering about how often an "outer function" (see below) is called).

Code:

```
def inner_func(i):
    print('called inner')
    return i

def outer_func(n):
    print('called outer')
    return range(n)

l = [inner_func(i) for i in outer_func(5)]
```

This will print `called outer` once and `called inner` 5 times, verifying that, just as in a normal for loop, the outer function is executed once and the inner function once per loop.